# How can i send a video mediastream from React js to Python using Websocket?

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket, fastapi

My objective is to send a user's video stream as array buffer to python using websocket. I am confused about how to make getUserMedia stream an array and send it to python using fastapi websocket.

I am Sharing some important parts of my attempted code, hoping somebody help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

**My Attempted Code:**

**React js--**

```
const userStream = useRef([]);

useEffect(() => {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: true }).then(stream => {
  userStream.current.srcobject = stream;
```

> Cannot figure out the process for creating userStream an array object

```
  var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws')
  socket.onopen = () => socket.send(userStream.current.srcobject)

  socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log("[message] Data received from server:");
    if (event.data !== undefined && event.data !== null) {
      console.log(event.data)
    }
  }

  socket.onclose = () => {
    console.log("Connection Closed!");
  };
    
  socket.onerror = () => {
    console.log("WS Error");
  };

  return () => {
    socket.close();
  };
    });

}, []);

return (
    <div>
        <video controls style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }} autoPlay ref={userStream} />
    </div>
);
```

**Python Code--**

> Cannot figure out to process the data received from front end

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket  

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, data_image):
print("Accepting Connection")
await websocket.accept()
print('Accepted')
while True:
    try:

        image_bytes = await websocket.receive_bytes()
        print('Image Received')
        nparr = np.frombuffer(image_bytes, np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        # Do something with the image here
        # ...
        # Send a response back (optional)
        _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
        response_bytes = buffer.tobytes()
        
        await websocket.send_bytes(response_bytes)
    except:
        pass
        break
```